# getting error message "This app is incompatible with all of your devices" when uploading app

Tags: android, google-play

I have recently uploaded [my first beta application to the market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.olszewski.android.workout&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5vbHN6ZXdza2kuYW5kcm9pZC53b3Jrb3V0Il0).

For some reason I am getting a message saying that it is incompatible with all of my devices.
I have not loaded it on any of my devices, I do have an install button, and it is designed for android 2.3.3 (I'm running 2.3.4). It also does not appear on the market for my phone, any ideas as to what is going on and how to remedy it?

Comment: Can you share your manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

Your `AndroidManifest.xml` says

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
```

which is Android 4.0.3 so it won't run on 2.3. Change it to 9 or 10 or whatever you need.

in Eclipse: `Project > Properties |> Android` change the project build target to that version too if required.